# Import a string as parameter to Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

This is for `CR10` desktop, not an `SDK`.

Is there a way to import a string into the report? The report will use this string and `Split` it by comma to find all records where a field matches one in the list. The `Split` part with the check in a function I can write, just need to know how I can import this string if poss. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by importing a string

Comment: I will have a function that parses that string which will be comma separated to check if a field value matches any of the items in the string array

Comment: You can use a text file as a data source for a subreport. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027443/is-it-possible-to-show-the-contents-of-a-text-file-in-crystal-reports).

Comment: @Ryan Looks interesting. Not sure how to use a `Sub Report` in a function though.

Comment: @OneFineDay The general idea would be to use the subreport to build the string and save it off into a shared variable. Then you'd be able to manipulate/iterate over it in the main report just like any other string.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Sub Reports. I will have to research that. Thanks

Comment: Are you adding this report in your project? In that case parameter string can be passed from the same and you can fetch and manipulate data. There has to be some source to provide that string.

Comment: No, there is no project. This is in Crystal Reports IDE.